# C++ - Function able to access a class method without it being static or object being created

Tags: c++

I came across this code recently

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A 
{
public:
    void foo() const { cout << "A::foo() const\n"; }
    void foo() { cout << "A::foo()\n"; }
};

A bar() { return A(); }
const A cbar() { return A(); }
int main()
{
    bar().foo();
    cbar().foo();
}
```

I read this part about the return statement from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return :
Evaluates the expression, terminates the current function and returns the result of the expression to the caller, after implicit conversion to the function return type.
Is A() an expression? Prior to coming across this code, I would not have thought that it was even a valid syntax.

A bar() basically means the return type of bar() is A, but
I have two questions:
1) What does A() and return A() do inside the function bar()?
2) How can bar() access foo() in A class without it being static? - I mean we haven't even defined an object for class A.

Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) What does A() and return A() do inside the function bar()?

`A bar() { return A(); }` returns an object by value. Here `A()` is the construction of the new object that will be returned.

> 2) How can bar() access foo() in A class without it being static? - I mean we haven't even defined an object for class A.

`bar()` creates a temporary, which you can call `const` functions on. It's almost like the following:

```
{
  A _tmp(bar());
  _tmp.foo();
}
```

A temporary comes into scope for the duration of the expression `bar().foo()`. The return value of `bar` initializes it, and we call a member function on that instance. Then it immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: so bar() creates a temporary A() object? Could you please elaborate a little more on that.

Comment: @TheNovice, was writing it when you commented :)

Comment: Thanks - This explains a lot.

Answer (score 3):

1. A is the class name, but calling A() means calling the constructor(a.k.a construction function) of class A. When a constructor is called, it generates one instance of that class. In this case, you didn't provide your customized constructor, so the default constructor with no parameter is provided by the compiler.

`return A();` returns what is returned by `A()`. Yes, the instance you've just created is returned.

2. The key is: to know "what bar() is, after it is called and executed".

   > I mean we haven't even defined an object for class A.

Of course you have. Calling `bar()` does this exactly.

Comment: Constructors don't actually have names. You can't reference them.

Comment: @StoryTeller There may be something inappropriate in my expression. Does it look better now?

Comment: It is better. But you'd notice that my answer deliberately avoid the phrases "calling a constructor" or "constructor function". Constructors are fairly unusual beasts in c++. You can't reference them, and only the compiler is allowed to "call them". That's why I specifically said "constructing an object".